# How can i get a auto generated primary key id from a table after completion of insertion query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert in two table. but for insertion in second table i need the latest id of the first table after insertion in first table. since second table is to many to many relation of first table and another table.
table1(id, name, age) and table2(id, street, table1_id). 1st i will insert into table1 then the id of the inserted row will insert into table2 as table1_id. how i can get the id of last inserted row of table1.

Comment: please try to put your code

Comment: Are you referring to [`*_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)?

Comment: `$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use `mysql_insert_id();`  just after your insert query like this:

```
$sql_save12 = mysql_query("insert into table(classId,pay_mode_id,) values ('44','2',)");

$insert = mysql_insert_id();
```

`$insert` will be your new inserted id.